# RxJs Websocket : Object's property (object) with no defined type not sent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs

Using rxjs websocket, I'm facing an issue when sending data.

I always wrap the message I send into a Request object that looks like this :

```
export class Request {
    public constructor() { }

    private t: string = null;
    public get type(): string {return this.t;}
    public set type(type: string) {this.t = type;}

    private i: string = null;
    public get issuer(): string {return this.i;}
    public set issuer(issuer: string) {this.i = issuer;}

    private n: string = null;
    public get name(): string {return this.n;}
    public set name(name: string) {this.n = name;}

    private c: MyCandidateClass = null;
    public get candidate(): MyCandidateClass {return this.c;}
    public set candidate(candidate: MyCandidateClass) {this.c = candidate;}

    private cis: { [id: string]: string; } = {};
    public get credentialsInfo(): { [id: string]: string; } {return this.cis;}
    public set credentialsInfo(credentialsInfo: { [id: string]: string; }) {this.cis = credentialsInfo;}
}
```

The object is built, and my `cis` property is a key/value map which value can be for example `{_PinCode: "1234"}`.

Everything is fine in my request object, but here is what's actually sent to the websocket server :

```
{
    cis: {},
    c: candidate // <- an object of class MyCandidateClass as expected
    i: "some_username",
    n: "some_name",
    t: "some_type"
}
```

I am losing the `cis` object.

---

While investigating, I noticed that if I create a class `CredentialsInfo` with the correct properties inside and change my `cis` property from `Request` like the following :

```
private cis: CredentialsInfo = null;
public get credentialsInfo(): CredentialsInfo {return this.cis;}
public set credentialsInfo(credentialsInfo: CredentialsInfo) {this.cis = credentialsInfo;}
```

With these modifications, it works just fine.

However, I want my `cis` to be key/value map as defined in my initial `Request`, not a defined type of my own since I can't always know what will the map keys be.

I'm guessing this has to deal with default serialization/deserialization ?

How can I achieve this, and make the initial `Request` work ?

Note : I'm using Angular and rxjs, here are some relevant parts of my websocket service :

```
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
// ...
  ws: WebSocketSubject<any> = null;
// ...
  connect(): void {
// ...
    this.ws = webSocket(this.websocketUrl);
    this.ws.subscribe(
      (response) => this.onReceive(ResponseInfo.map(response)),
      (err) => this.onError(err),
      () => this.onClose('Complete (connection closed)')
    );
// ...
  }

  send(request: RequestInfo): void {
    // ...
    this.ws.next(request);
  }
// ...
```

Comment: do you know what are the possible attributes of cis, or do you want it to not be defined? also, if you change the type of cis (and of the getter) to any, does the request work as intended?

Comment: `any` or `object` type are not working neither. I want this to be generic so, I dont know for sure what the cis attributes can be, I would create a class for it if I did.

Comment: maybe it can't handle nested objects for some reason, just for the sake of trying, can you spread (...cis) to your request object and see if all the properties are sent?